# Different between 頂くand いただく？

Tags: grammar, kanji

Is it incorrect to use the kanji for いただくif it is used as an auxiliary verb. For example ご提供頂く is incorrect but ご提供いただく is right?
Can kanji be used if いただく is being used as a main verb?

Comment: I always thought 頂く is just the kanji for いただく...Isn't this the case? I always see them used interchangeably

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, it is exactly as you say.

> 「頂{いただ}く」 as a verb

「先生{せんせい}から手紙{てがみ}を頂いた。」 (I received a letter from the teacher.)

> 「いただく」 as a subsidiary verb

「先生に作文{さくぶん}を読{よ}んでいただいた。」 (The teacher [kindly] read the composition for me.)

In that sentence, the verb is 「読む」 and the subsidiary verb 「いただく」.

There are, however, native speakers who write the subsidiary verb 「いただく」 using kanji as 「頂く」 with the misbelief that the more kanji they use, the better educated they are.  They are usually corrected at work, if not while in school, (unless their bosses do not know any better).

To know kanji, you would need to be educated, but to know when not to use kanji, you would need to be even more educated.  Some Japanese-learners become so obsessed with kanji that they end up writing everything using kanji.  Be careful; SE is no exception.  The misbelief "the more kanji the more educated" is quite remarkable here.

Comment: So the same as 行く/いく and 来る/くる? I get it now. Learnt something new!